# onload animation delay of child elements of a div with js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

i have div, inside which i have made 3 card inside it and animated it as slide in. I can delay animation using nth child, but i want to do it with java script .children property and apply animation delay as --> index + 's'   [my code] (https://codepen.io/beastop/pen/mdVMNgY)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution for your query using jQuery.

```js
$(function(){
  var seconds = 0.8;
  $('.container').children('.card').css({
    "animation": `slide ${seconds}s ease-out`
  })
});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
 }

.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  }

.card{
  width:40px;
  height: 40px;
  background:black;
  transition: transfrom 2s ease;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

@keyframes slide{
  0%{
    transform: translatex(-50px);
    }
  100%{
    transform: translatex(0px);
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sprite animation to individual class,
like this:

#### CSS

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
 }

.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  }

.card{
  width:40px;
  height: 40px;
  background:black;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.slide-anim{
  animation: slide 2s ease-out;
  transition: transfrom 2s ease;
}

@keyframes slide{
  0%{
    transform: translatex(-50px);
    }
  100%{
    transform: translatex(0px);
    }
  }
```

#### Html

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card slide-anim"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="toggleSlides()">toggle</button>
```

#### JS

```js
function toggleSlides() {
  var cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    var card = cards[i];
    if (card.classList) {
      card.classList.toggle("slide-anim");
    } else {
      // For IE9
      var classes = card.className.split(" ");
      var i = classes.indexOf("slide-anim");

      if (i >= 0) classes.splice(i, 1);
      else classes.push("slide-anim");
      card.className = classes.join(" ");
    }
  }
}
```

### you can use jquery for fast way

jquery animations work greate